# Web API 2 Routing

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm fairly new to API Routing and trying to get my head around this problem.

Lets assume we have an List of Candy Bars.

I want todo the following:

```
ListAllCandyBars      --- api/Candy
ListCandyBar via ID   --- api/Candy/10
ListAllChocBars       --- api/Candy/Choc
```

Therefore we have 3 GETS

Default Get
Get with ID
Action Get

How would you expect to set up the Routes and Class. I only ever seem to be able to get either ListAllCandyBars and ListCandyBar via ID or ListAllCandyBars and ListAllChocBars working.

This is my current Route:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "WithActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Using something like this:

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Default
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET: api/Default/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // GET: api/Default/ListSub
        public string ListSub(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Default
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/Default/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Default/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
     }
```

Look forward to hearing from you and getting past this little issue. PS It might be my understanding of Controllers. Should I have a different controller for ListAllChocBars?

Regards

James

Comment: Use route attributes instead of mapping them in the config

Comment: That works a treat thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over complicating and going for route attributes only worked really well.